# How does one migrate from OAuth 1 2LO to OAuth Domain-Wide Delegation For Google APIs?

Tags: google-oauth

I have a large customer base and would like to migrate them from using OAuth1 2LO to OAuth2 Domain-Wide Delegation and

1) Would like to know if it's possible.

2) If possible, can it be done without user intervention/impact.

For reference, I am looking at/following the OAuth1 migration doc (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#migration):

According to the delegation docs, we'd want to create a "service account", but the OAuth1 -> OAuth2 migration guide (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#migration)

> Your application must have an OAuth 2.0 Client ID. You get this Client ID by registering the application as an installed app or a web app in the Google Cloud Console.

1) Does this also work for "service accounts"?

If the migration does work for service accounts, there appear to be manual steps on the part of the admin for setting up delegation (found here: https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation)

> The service account that you created now needs to be granted access to the Google Apps domain’s user data that you want to access. The following tasks have to be performed by an administrator of the Google Apps domain:...

2) Does this mean that we will require our customers to complete these steps ?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no token migration involved for the delegation case (so, ignore the migrations docs: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#migration).

In order to migrate to OAuth2 in this case, you will have to implement Google's 2-legged OAuth2. For information on how to do so, check out [Google's 2-legged OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and [Google Drive SDK delegation](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation) docs.

Hope that helps!